# Emacs frozen when typing commands for gdb

Tags: emacs, gdb

Environment: Windows 7, emacs-25.2

I use gdb-mi(gdb many windows) to debug my program and it works find till I try to type commands for the breakpoint with command "(gdb) commands"

```
......
(gdb) run
(gdb) break 7
(gdb) commands
Type commands for breakpoint(s) 2, one per line.
End with a line saying just "end".
>sile -- Oops emacs frozen
```

Emacs frozen with a warning message "blocking call to accept-process-output with quit inhibited!!"

Sadly, "C-g","ESC","C-]" can't help but force quit

How to fix this issue? TX

There are some explanations for why "inhibited quit" happens

1) [Link](http://emacs.1067599.n8.nabble.com/Blocking-call-to-accept-process-output-with-quit-inhibited-11-times-td149496.html)

```
It means just that: accept-process-output is called in a way that can 
block (e.g. because some remote host doesn't respond) wit inhibit0quit 
set to a non-nil value, which means that Emacs may end up frozen (with 
no way to wake it up) for as long as the remote machine decides not 
to answer.
```

2) [Link](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck/issues/318)

```
The Blocking call message is an emacs "bug" as far as I can tell. It happens 
when you call an external program (like javac) from a timer, as flycheck 
would do.
```

Comment: This will not solve the problem, but if you have an urgent debug you can always use gdb without emacs by using the -tui option: simply type "gdb -tui file_to_debug"

Comment: @PicaudVincent Thanks for your comment, I use gdb in emacs's shell and it works find now : )